# Handcuffs found by Yuri

Tags: plot-explanation, fortitude

In the second episode of [Fortitude](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498622/?ref_=nv_sr_1) we see Yuri entering the empty police station in order to return the rifle that the sheriff lent him.
While searching through the place he finds a pair of handcuffs with an inscription on them.
He examines the handcuffs, looks surprised and swears.

What was so specific about these handcuffs? Do we know what was written on them?

In episode 6 we find out that **some** handcuffs [are important to the plot](http://www.theguardian.com/sky-atlantic-fortitude/2015/mar/06/fortitude-handcuffs-at-dawn-episode-6). Are these the same handcuffs? If so, how did Yuri know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in [Episode 10](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3778130/?ref_=ttep_ep10), but since this is a later episode to that in the question, I'll throw the explanation in spoiler tags:

> Pettigrew and Yuri were friends/partners.  In the flashback, we see Pettigrew use his handcuffs when attacking Elena, and Dan then use the same handcuffs to attach him to the pylon.  Yuri clearly recognised these in Dan's desk and so realised then that Dan was responsible for Pettigrew's death.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't watched episode 10 yet and I won't do it soon. I will read (and probably accept) your answer afterwards.

Comment: I've replaced your link with a link to this episode in IMDB, as yours is not working anymore. Thanks again for the answer.